# When the user reloads the page, he can't get the information storaged on back-end arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript, socket.io

I'm using socket io to develop an application and i'm with doubt in something, i have an array on back-end and when the user reloads the page he connects with socket.io but he can't acess the previous info storaged, how this connection works and have some technique to solve it ?

Comment: Please add some code about what you have done

Answer (score -1):

Not enough data. Post your code here. Maybe you should add your script into the document.onload part. I would rather use a simple ajax request to fetching a variable from the server, either with jQuery.ajax(), or fetch() or xmlHttpRequest